# Creating a macro that resets file and saves as new day

Tags: vba, excel

At work, I've been trying to create a macro that will automatically clear a certain range - only content -, the range being B78:G83.

After clearing this range, I'd like the macro to save the current file under a new name. The new name should be the current day, with format "dd mmmm" (two digits for the name, a space in between and then the full month's name)

The file path is (f.e.)

"T:\RESERVATIONS\Duty Report\2017\4. April\25 april"

with the year, month and current date being variable (as we make separate folders for these files at work).

```
Sub NieuweDag()
'
' NieuweDag Macro
' Invoer wissen en opslaan als nieuwe dag
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+q
'
    Range("B78:G83").Select
    Range("G82").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim NewName As String

    FilePath = "T:\RESERVATIONS\Duty Report\": NewName = FilePath & Year(Now()) & "\" & Month(Now()) & ". " & MonthName(Now()) & "\" & Format(Date, "dd mmmm") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

This is what I've got but it doesn't work. I get Error 5. It's in dutch, so allow me to translate:

> Error 5 during launch:
>
> Invalid procedure-call or invalid argument

Anyone out here be able to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper format is MonthName(number of month, [abbreviate]), you should use

```
MonthName(Month(Now()))
```

instead of

```
MonthName(Now())
```

Plus, you can enhance your code by using

```
Range("B78:G83").ClearContents
```

instead of

```
Range("B78:G83").Select
Range("G82").Activate
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves the problem indeed, thanks for the (very) quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the amount of coding required to create `NewName` by changing

```
NewName = FilePath & Year(Now()) & "\" & Month(Now()) & ". " & MonthName(Now()) & "\" & Format(Date, "dd mmmm") & ".xlsm"
```

to

```
NewName = FilePath & Format(Now(), "yyyy\\m. mmmm\\dd mmmm") & ".xlsm"
```